# How to make my app on EC2 access Redis on ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-ecs

I have a software infra on AWS where part of the app runs on an EC2 instance and another part on ECS Fargate cluster.

I'm having trouble getting my application, which runs on the EC2 instance, to access a specific container that runs on ECS. More clearly, I need to make my application on EC2 access Redis on ECS. Is possible to do this kind of integration?

Both parts of the application are in the same VPC and have Security Groups that authorize access to each other.

**More context:**

Every time the Task Definition is provisioned in ECS Fargate, my public/private network IP changes on cluster service. To be able to access the services, Amazon provides the Service Discovery configuration, which updates a DNS hosted zone whenever there is a change in the ECS network.

My problem is using this hosted zone within my EC2 instances. I can access ECS containers directly via IP, but this is not the ideal scenario. The IP address constantly changes whenever the service is provisioned. On the other hand, on my EC2 instances, the Route 53 nameserver always appears as unknown.

My cloud is configured as follows:

**Task Definition**

```json
{
  "family": "******",
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::******",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "runtimePlatform": {
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
  },
  "cpu": "2048",
  "memory": "4096",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "redis",
      "image": "redis:alpine",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 6379,
          "hostPort": 6379
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**ECS Service config**
ECS service network settings:

[image: ECS Service config]

**Route 53**
Container auto discovery is enabled for the service in ECS:

[image: Route 53 Container auto discovery]

The A record IP is updated whenever the ECS service is provisioned.

**ECS Security Group Inbound Rules for my EC2 instance:**

My ECS container is open for connections from my EC2 instance. Connections to Redis via ECS service IP are successful, but connections via generated nameserver aren't.

[image: Security Group]

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you having trouble figuring out what hostname to use in your Redis connection settings? Or are you getting an error message when you try to connect? Please be specific in the details of your question, and include any relevant error messages.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I wonder, why you would run redis in ECS Fargate instead of using the Amazon Elasticache Redis https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache

But, if you really want to do this, you should have at least the following configuration:

- NLB or ALB, that points to your service

- target group to the service

- your "redis" service

- your task definition

Place all of your services eigther into the same security group or add inbound/outbound with the corresponding security group. Do not forget the add the port 6379 fir inbound/outbound rule.

Pointing directly to the container is no good practice because restarting/scaling of the container will change the ip address.

If you compare the costs of ALB or NLB (doing so, I would prefer ALB with a listener on Port 6379) and the costs for Fargate, you will be able to use a medium sized t3/t4g instance of Elasticache Redis.

I did a lot of comparisons of "self hosted" or "managed service" and there are not much reasons, to run services by your own, if there is an alternative managed service from AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the recommendation to use Amazon ElastiCache instead of a Redis container. However, the use of Redis was to illustrate the scenario, it is not Redis that is running on ECS but another part of my app. My question is more related to the network settings. I believe that the path is with an NLB or ALB, as you mentioned, but I don't know exactly how it should be configured.